# Entity Framework Exception at run time: Entities in participate in the relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity

While using code first approach when I run my project. During new user registration, the entity framework is throwing this exception:

`Additional information: Entities in 'ApplicationDbContext.IdentityUsers' participate in the 'ApplicationUser_UserDetails' relationship. 0 related 'ApplicationUser_UserDetails_Target' were found. 1 'ApplicationUser_UserDetails_Target' is expected.`

The exception was thrown:

```
var manager = new UserManager();
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = UserName.Text };
//This line At the time of creating user
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
```

I created the schema code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public Nullable<DateTime> DateOfCreation { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> LastLogin { get; set; }
        public UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TaskSheetManagement> TaskSheet { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
    }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasKey(pk => pk.Id).ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(pk=>pk.Id).ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetails>().HasKey(pk => pk.UserDetailId).ToTable("UserDetails");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(p => p.UserDetails).WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.ApplicationUser);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(t => t.UserName).IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(14)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
                new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("U_Username", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetails>()
                .Property(t => t.Email).IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(25)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
                new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("U_Email", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

And UserDetails is:

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Nic { get; set; }
    public string ResidentAddress { get; set; }
    public string CellNO { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Religion { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

I couldn't find out what this exception is related to. I searched google and implemeted other solutions but couldn't resolve. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a 1:1 association, but 1:1 associations do not work this way in Entity Framework.

1:1 Associations must share the same primary key.  The way you've defined this is two 1:M associations, and they conflict with each other.

If you want a 1:1, then you have to change your Primary Key for UserDetails to be Id, and then you have to map them together with something like:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetails>().HasRequired(x => x.ApplicationUser)
            .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.UserDetails);
```